# Limitations of Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I have been using Regular Expressions for a couple years now and feel comfortable with them, but I was wondering if there are any limitations when using them. I know about the limitations related to recursion (discussed here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx ). Are there any limitations related to memory? I assume you can capture a string as large as you can fit in memory (or that the VM will allow you to).

Are there any other limitations with regex's that I should know about?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: You really need to specify the regex engine you are using, since each one has different limits. Some have gone as far as to allow some grammar-like regexes. Looking through tchrist's (Tom Christiansen) answers here on SO you can get an idea of the power some regex engines have reached.

Answer (score 10):

Regexs can only parse regular grammers anything context-free and higher you need a stack (i.e. a real parser).

That is their only **real** limitation, performance depends the particular implementation, but generally is slow even precompiled compared to a state machine.

Comment: -1: most regex engines (with the posible exception of re2, which I have not looked carefully at) have gone beyond pure regular expressions.

Comment: So you are one of the "purists" that don't recognize stack able regexes?

Comment: @ninjalj I was not aware of 'non-regular' regular expressions, could you point me to an example or article?  Thanks.

Comment: @Gnon: back-references can create non-regular languages, and I think they have been in use since at least the early 70s.

Comment: @Gnon: and about 'non-regular regexes', that's why Larry Wall suggested we call these thingies regexes or regexps, and _not_ regular expressions, since they are no longer regular.

Comment: This is the correct answer - from a formal grammar standpoint

Answer (score 8):

Ginormous regexes can be quite slow and memory hungry. I know, because I have created one. It can tokenize what shouldn't be tokenized by a regex. :-) if you want a link... Now... I haven't ever benchmarked "small" regexes so I don't know their speed. They surely *are* compact to write.

Ah I was forgetting, regexes are The Evil. Their main problem is that they are like an hammer and when you have them, you try to make all the problems be like a nail. So their main problem is in the user (the programmer).

First "big" limitation: Javascript implements only a subset of them, with no Unicode support. Normally the language you use server side has a more complete implementation, so you get limited by js. Even quite complete implementations like the .NET one have big limits: no support for surrogate pairs and no support for "composed" characters (characters that use combining mark). But, as always, the problem is in the programmer. How many programmers that know Unicode know the intricacies of Unicode, of the various sets of digits, of the diacritics?

Second "big" limitation: maintainability. They are complex and unreadable when they are written. But months later? They get worse! And if you have to train a new programmer, now he has to learn one more language: regex.

Third "big" limitation: they hide too much. You see `\d\s\d`. What does it means? a digit a space and a digit? Surely. But both `\d` and `\s` in the .NET Regexes "hide" a microworld. `\d` "matches" any non-european digit (and there are many many ones in Unicode). `\s` "matches" so many esoteric spaces of which I don't even know the name... I don't even want to think about it. They are like icebergs. Only 1/8 is out of the water, while 7/8 is hidden. But it's that 7/8 that will probably kill you.

Comment: How is it regex's fault if JavaScript only supports a "subset"? And readability shouldn't be a problem either with verbose regexes (which, again, JavaScript doesn't support). Surely, you can write giant, performance-poor regexes if you don't know what you're doing (or abusing the tool), just as you can write bad programs in any language. And -1 for the unqualified "evil" classification that doesn't make an ounce of sense.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Giving faults to an object is always stupid. The fault is in the stupid human that created/projected it. Regexes don't have faults. They are fault**y**. And they are fault**y** not only because they are fault**y** but because 1) they are child of another era, a more simple era without unicode or internationalization and 2) every programmer "improved" them in a different way. In the same way they aren't *evil*, like a gun isn't *evil*, but like guns, they make persons do stupider things.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Now, the fact that there are many different implementations of Regexes... This in a way is a problem. In the same way that when there were many unixes (not compatible one with another) this "fragmentation" was a problem. If I have to write a Regex in ASP.Net, I know I can only use the subset available on JS in I want to use it client side and server side. Oh yeah, I have a Ferrari, but I have to go on dirt roads... woah!

Comment: @TimPietzcker And on the effect of Regexes on programmer... Well... You responded to 1100 questions of Regexes. You know what the "standard" question is. "i'm too much lazy to study the ten pages of manual of regexes (and I think that in ten pages you can write quite much of regexes), but I have decided that I **need** Regexes (in the same way that I **need** to breath) to do xxxx yyyy. Please write it to me".

Comment: @TimPietzcker You told me why you gave me a -1... Now you should tell me why you took it away :-) :-)

Comment: I find many good points in your comments :)

Answer (score 5):

Limitations

1. Cannot solve everything. ( anyone on SO would say what happens
   when you try to parse HTML with regex)
2. Should not be used for
   everything - readability and performance issues. Use where appropriate. Not for simple task, like substrings of  string, and also not for complex task.

Bottomline, it is a tool. Use it like any other tool. Don't over use it. Don't let it be the only tool in your toolkit.